Offline Image Not Displaying J4
Joomla 4.4.5, fresh install.
When I set an offline image in the Joomla admin area Global Config > Site, it doesn't display on the front end. I am using the default Joomla offline file located at templates\system\offline.php
In the oomla admin area I have selected the following image from the Select input;
images/powered_by.png#joomlaImage://local-images/powered_by.png?width=294&height=44. ##I can see the image in the admin Offline Image preview box, but not the front end.
Cleared all caches etc.
Any ideas?
